# How do I store (scanf) a randomly generated number? ( Code inside)

Tags: c, random, scanf

This is the code i used to generate the number:

```
printf("%d\n", rand()%10);
```

I am creating a card game HiLo. I want to know how to store the number generated from that and then make the user guess wether the next number is going to be higher or lower than the previous. After that, another number is generated and not stored just yet. I want to compare the new number with the old number too see if the user is correct (alot points) and then store the new number.

Comment: Sorry, didnt mention it. But this is in C.

Comment: What do you mean by "store"? Do you want it in a variable? If so, try `int r = rand()%10; printf("%d\n",r);` Then do whatever you want with r. Declare int rPrev outside the loop. At the end of the loop, store r in rPrev. Next time you start at the top of the loop block, rPrev will be the previous value. I don't see how you want `scanf` for this.

Comment: Yea i mean store as a variable. Is rPrev a method of using the previous value of that variable? So if i use "r" along with any other variable, will it use the previous value of that variable?

Comment: Nevermind, ignore my comment above. I understood what you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to use a variable.  All variables may include alphabetic characters, as well as numeric characters, however the first character must be alphabetic.  The concept of creating a variable is that you are creating an area of temporary storage for the successful operation of your program.  Any areas of code using a particular variable are considered to be dependent on it, and variables work in "scopes".  Scopes are started using the `{` character and are ended using the `}` character.  Any variables declared between these characters are usable only within those characters, and not outside of them, as they do not exist except within those characters.

I have created an example of the program I believe you are trying to write in order to demonstrate the software programming practices involved in such a task.

The example is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH_OF_BUFFER 100

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int prevRandomNumber = rand() % 10;
    int continuePlaying = 1;

    while( continuePlaying == 1 )
    {
        int randomNumber = rand() % 10;
        int userSelection = 0;
        char lineBuffer[LENGTH_OF_BUFFER];
        printf( "Previous random number %d\n", prevRandomNumber );

        while( userSelection == 0 )
        {
            printf( "higher or lower?" );
            gets( lineBuffer );

            if ( strcmp( "higher", lineBuffer ) == 0 )
            {
                userSelection = 1;
                printf( "You selected higher!\n" );
            }
            else if ( strcmp( "lower", lineBuffer ) == 0 )
            {
                userSelection = -1;
                printf( "You selected lower!\n" );
            }
            else
            {
                printf( "Sorry, I didn't understand you, please check your input and try again!\n" );
            }
        }

        if ( userSelection == 1 )
        {
            if ( randomNumber > prevRandomNumber )
            {
                printf( "Correct, you really are a marvel!\n" );
            }
            else
            {
                printf( "Incorrect, I pity you!\n" );
            }
        }
        else if ( userSelection == -1 )
        {
            if ( randomNumber < prevRandomNumber )
            {
                printf( "Correct, you really are a marvel!\n" );
            }
            else
            {
                printf( "Incorrect, I pity you!\n" );
            }
        }

        printf( "Number was %d\n", randomNumber );

        printf( "Care to play again?\n" );
        gets( lineBuffer );

        prevRandomNumber = randomNumber;

        if ( strcmp( "yes", lineBuffer ) != 0 )
        {
            continuePlaying = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = rand()%10;
int nextNumber;
char choice;
while(choice != 'Q' && choice != 'q')
{
    printf("Current Number is : %d",number);
    printf("\nYou want to guess the next number : ");
    printf("\nPress L if number will be greater than current number ");
    printf("\nPress S if number will be smaller than current number ");
    printf("\nPress Q if you want to quit playing : ");
    Printf("\n\nEnter your choice : ")
    scanf("%c",&choice);
    nextNumber = rand()%10;
    if(choice == 'L' || choice == 'l')
    {
        if(nextNumber > number)
        {
            printf("\nYour Guess is Right...");
        }   
        else
        {
            printf("\nYour Guess is wrong...");
        }
    }
    else if(choice == 'L' || choice == 'l')
    {
        if(nextNumber < number)
        {
            printf("\nYour Guess is Right...");
        }   
        else
        {
            printf("\nYour Guess is wrong...");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nYour choice is invalid. Try Again...");
    }   
    number = nextNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    char* bet, cmd;
    long random_number, new_random_number;
    while (1)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));

        random_number = rand();
        printf("%d\n", random_number);
        printf("bet if the next number is bigger (+) or lower (-): ");
        scanf("%s",bet);

        srand(time(NULL));
        new_random_number = rand();

        printf("%d\n", new_random_number);

        /* TODO - you might want to put that into a function some how */
        if ( bet[0] == '+')
        {
            if ( new_random_number >= random_number ) /* user is correct */
            {
                printf("yeah! you are right\n");
                printf("\nlet's play again!!\n");
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("trololol :P That was wrong\n");
                printf("\nlet's play again!!\n");
                continue;
            }
        }

        if ( bet[0] == '-')
        {
            if ( new_random_number < random_number ) /* user is correct */
            {
                printf("yeah! you are right\n");
                printf("\nlet's play again!!\n");
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("trololol :P That was wrong\n");
                printf("\nlet's play again!!\n");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

/* vim: set et sw=4 ts=4: */
```